# Wierd clear bar

Tags: css, html

So while developing my website I ran into a small problem.
This is what shows up after I made another section.
[image]

My CSS:
[Pastebin Link](http://pastebin.com/kYayQssc)

HTML: 
[Pastebin Link](http://pastebin.com/JMp8qyND)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your problem is coming from the pesky `<h1>` element. By default, they have a margin so that white line you are seeing is the `<h1>`'s margin. Don't worry you can remove it by settings its margin to 0 in your CSS.

I like to use the `*` to declare styles I want by default.

Here is an example.

```
* {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}
```

This way everything has no padding or margin!

Hopes this helps.

Comment: It works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

@TinoCaer beat me to it.

```
h1 {
   margin: 0;
}
```

but you can still use padding to style your h1.

```
h1 {
  padding: 1em;
}
```